# php session start error

Tags: php, api

I have page as part of a checkout process using a 3rd party API that comes up with this error:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /upgrades/upgradevip.php:1) in /upgrades/upgradevip.php on line 1

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /upgrades/upgradevip.php:1) in /upgrades/upgradevip.php on line 1

WHat line in the php code do I need to change to get this to work?

Here's the code:

```
<?php session_start();

include('./includes/config.php');
include('./includes/functions.php');
include('./lib/recurly.php');

$message='';

// Required for the API
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = API_KEY;
// Optional for Recurly.js:
Recurly_js::$privateKey = PRIVATE_KEY;


$acc=get_querystring_var_val('account');
$plan=get_querystring_var_val('plan');
$subid=get_querystring_var_val('subid');
$aff=get_querystring_var_val('aff');
$firstname=get_querystring_var_val('firstname');
$lastname=get_querystring_var_val('lastname');
$email=get_querystring_var_val('email');
$phonenumber=get_querystring_var_val('phonenumber');
$brand=get_querystring_var_val('brand');
$zip=get_querystring_var_val('zip');


if(isset($_POST['process']) && $_POST['process'] =='1'){

    /*
    * get all session info to process
    */

    $selCardType=get_session_val('selCardType');
    $txtCCNumber=get_session_val('txtCCNumber');
    $txtSecurityCode=get_session_val('txtSecurityCode');
    $selMonth=get_session_val('selMonth');
    $selYear=get_session_val('selYear');

    $account_code=$acc;

    if($account_code!=''){

        /*
        * process transaction
        */

        $transaction = new Recurly_Transaction();
        $transaction->description = $upsell_description;
        $transaction->amount_in_cents = $upsell_amount_in_cents;
        $transaction->currency = CURRENCY_CODE;

        $account = new Recurly_Account();
        $account->account_code = $account_code;

        $billing_info = new Recurly_BillingInfo();
        $billing_info->first_name = $firstname;
        $billing_info->last_name = $lastname;
        $billing_info->number = $txtCCNumber;
        $billing_info->verification_value = $txtSecurityCode;
        $billing_info->month = $selMonth;
        $billing_info->year = $selYear;
        $billing_info->zip = $zip;


        $account->billing_info = $billing_info;
        $transaction->account = $account;



        $success=false;
        try{
            $transaction->create();
            $success=true;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message='There was problem processing your request.' . $e;
        }


        if($success){
            /*
            * set one time transaction details in session
            */
            try {
                $transactions = Recurly_TransactionList::getForAccount($account_code);
                foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
                  //print "$subscription\n";
                  //echo '<br/><br/>';
                  $_SESSION['onetime_receipt']=$transaction->uuid;
                }
            } catch (Recurly_NotFoundError $e) {
                //$message= "Transaction not found" . $e;
            }
            header('Location: /congratulations2deff5-us.php?account='. $acc.'&plan=' . $plan.'&subid=' . $subid.'&aff='.$aff.'&firstname='.$firstname.'&lastname=' .$lastname. '&email=' .$email .'&phonenumber='.$phonenumber.'&brand=' . $brand . '&zip=' . $zip);
            exit;

        }else{
            //ideally this is place to set a variable to show a form which asks a user to fill contact info and cc info agaian
            $message='Transaction could not be processed';
        }
    }else{
        $message='There was problem processing your request.';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: The errors indicate that there were some content outputted already to the browser. You need to make sure there's no output yet when you call the function. Is `upgradevip.php` an included file inside another one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have spaces before the opening `<?php` tag, remove them.

Comment: unbelievable, i was just writing the same exact reply :)

Comment: there are no spaces, just a mistake when creating the post

Comment: Is this file included in another one ?

Comment: this code is the beginning part before the html portion of the upgradevip.php page

Comment: Perhaps some non-visual characters, not visible in your editor?

Comment: i dont know. how do you mean?

Comment: Some control character, that is not visible in your editor, but still gets outputted, causing the issue. Try opening your file in a different editor and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

and remove the leading spaces before

Answer (score 0):

Check that this php file is loaded very first (for example - this is "index.php"), but not included in index.php or elsewhere